# ¿Como cargar el treeview a medida que el usuario expanda los nodos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un treeview cargado de manera recursiva

```
private void CrearNodos(int indicePadre, TreeNode nodePadre)
{
        dataTableNodos = mCuentas.RecogerDatos(nombreBDUsada);
        DataView dataViewNodosHijos = new DataView(dataTableNodos);
        dataViewNodosHijos.RowFilter = dataTableNodos.Columns["IdPadre"].ColumnName + " = " + indicePadre;

        foreach (DataRowView dataFilas in dataViewNodosHijos)
        {
            TreeNode nuevoNodo = new TreeNode();
            nuevoNodo.Text = dataFilas["Codigo"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            nuevoNodo.Name = dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            nuevoNodo.Tag = dataViewNodosHijos.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dataFilas.Row);

            if (nodePadre == null)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
            }
            else
            {
                nodePadre.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
            }
            CrearNodos(Int32.Parse(dataFilas["IdPCuentas"].ToString()), nuevoNodo);
        }}
```

Y esa función la llamo en el `Load` del formulario, en estos momentos el `Treeview` tiene 352 nodos, entonces al abrir por primera vez el `formulario` tarda en que aparezcan los elementos y el `TreeView`, como mejoro el tiempo de carga? O como hago que el `TreeView` me cargue los 4 nodos principales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pienso que puedes probar sacar las dos primeras lineas fuera de tu función `CrearNodos` esas dos lineas tal como están ejecutaran exactamente lo mismo en cada llamada que se haga a la función recursiva `CrearNodos`. Por tanto no tienen por que estar dentro función, deberías incluir esas lineas en el punto anterior en donde realizas la llamada a la función recursiva, es decir dentro del `Load` del formulario

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataTable dataTableNodos = mCuentas.RecogerDatos(nombreBDUsada);
     DataView dataViewNodosHijos = new DataView(dataTableNodos);
     //Aquí realizas la llamada a la función CrearNodos.
     //pasando como argumento los objetos dataTableNodos, dataViewNodosHijos
     CrearNodos(dataTableNodos, dataViewNodosHijos, 0, null); 
 }

private void CrearNodos(DataTable dataTableNodos, DataView dataViewNodosHijos, int indicePadre, TreeNode nodePadre)
{
        dataViewNodosHijos.RowFilter = dataTableNodos.Columns["IdPadre"].ColumnName + " = " + indicePadre;

        foreach (DataRowView dataFilas in dataViewNodosHijos)
        {
            TreeNode nuevoNodo = new TreeNode();
            nuevoNodo.Text = dataFilas["Codigo"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            nuevoNodo.Name = dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            nuevoNodo.Tag = dataViewNodosHijos.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dataFilas.Row);

            if (nodePadre == null)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
            }
            else
            {
                nodePadre.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
            }
            CrearNodos(dataTableNodos, dataViewNodosHijos, Int32.Parse(dataFilas["IdPCuentas"].ToString()), nuevoNodo);
        }
}
```

En una función recursiva, es una regla elemental que no deben incluirse lineas de código, que ejecuten exactamente lo mismo en cada iteración, pues solo servirían para consumir tiempo de computo innecesario, ten en cuenta que si como dices tu `Treeview` tiene 352 nodos, esas dos lineas se estarían ejecutando 352 veces, tantas veces como se llame a la función recursiva.

Tal ves este arreglo no resuelva todos los problemas de optimización y la carga de los nodos no sea todo lo rápida que deseas, pero debe mejorar.

---

Otra cosa muy diferente seria agregar los nodos hijos, solo cuando el usuario expanda el nodo padre, para ello se puede usar el evento `BeforeExpand` del TreeView y agregar en ese evento solo sus nodos hijos, también es conveniente en este caso
declarar las variables DataTable dataTableNodos, DataView dataViewNodosHijos, al nivel del formulario, cargándolas en el `Load`.

```
void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Solo se agregaran los nodos si no los tiene ya agregados
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        //Recuperamos la propiedad Tag del nodo donde hemos almacenamos su índice, como veras más abajo
        dataViewNodosHijos.RowFilter = dataTableNodos.Columns["IdPadre"].ColumnName + " = " + Int32.Parse(e.Node.Tag.ToString());

        foreach (DataRowView dataFilas in dataViewNodosHijos)
        {
            TreeNode nuevoNodo = new TreeNode();
            nuevoNodo.Text = dataFilas["Codigo"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            nuevoNodo.Name = dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();
            //En la propiedad Tag almaceno el índice que lo asocia a la Fila correspondiente
            nuevoNodo.Tag = dataFilas["IdPCuentas"].ToString();
            e.Node.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
        }
    }
}
```

No obstante te recomiendo probar lo primero y si no te satisface puedes aplicar la segunda solución.

Comment: Gracias :), probé la primera sugerencia que me diste y me ayudo, la segunda no entendí muy bien, dices que tengo que cargar los primeros nodos y al expandir llamar los nodos hijos? De tomas maneras la primera opción me mejoro mucho el tiempo de carga

Comment: @Nathy En la segunda sugerencia, debes declarar las variables `dataTableNodos` y `dataViewNodosHijos` como `private` a nivel de la clase del `Form` luego en el `Load` del formulario, creas esas dos variables, similar a como se hizo en la primera sugerencia, solo que la declaración estará en la sección de declaraciones de la clase; para agregar los nodos que van en la raíz del `TreeView` es suficiente que en la función `CrearNodos` elimines la llamada recurrente a si misma, luego creas el evento `BeforeExpand` de tu `TreeView` y le agregas el código que te coloqué en la sugerencia.